# Virtual domains with wildcard?

Tags: postfix, domain, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to setup postfix to catch all emails from both: domain.tld & [randomsubdomain].domain.tld.

```
/((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+domain\.tld/ OK
```

This rule works very good, but unfortunately it's catching only mails for `[randomsubdomain].domain.tld`. Any mail to `domain.tld` is blocked with below error:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-xx[209.xx]: 554 5.7.1 <test@domain.tld>: Relay access denied;
```

`/home/admin/postfix/virtual_domains`:

```
/((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+domain\.tld/ OK
```

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = pcre:/home/admin/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps      = pcre:/home/admin/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

`/home/admin/postfix/virtual_aliases`:

```
/@((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+domain\.tld/ mailuser
```

Any ideas how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just do this:

`/home/admin/postfix/virtual_domains`:

```
/((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+domain\.tld/ OK
/^domain\.tld/ OK
```

and `/home/admin/postfix/virtual_aliases`:

```
/@((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+domain\.tld/ mailuser
/@domain\.tld/ mailuser
```

Was an easy one, wasn't it? If you want it more complicated you could rework the second lines into the first one, but then it looks more ugly.